# optimize performance of reading from sql view

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, view

I created view based on complex select query (takes 2 second to retrieve the data). When I'm trying to select data from this view based on a predicate, it takes more time (8 second). this is the query plan. what should I do to reduce this long time.
thank you.

execution plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1yeIvG1C

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarling.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: That's not the query plan. Please upload the actual execution plan's XML to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link it in your post.

Comment: @J.D. uploaded done

Comment: No the query plan for the function. As well as tables *and* index definitions. Hmmm, SQL Server 2008 R2 but not updated since release in 2010, I think I'll pass thank you. I sincerely hope that instance is completely firewalled and locked down.